# simple strings in python

Tags: python, string

This is only the second time I'm posting on this site and I have yet another small issue.  Here is my code:

```
results = ["2^0 = 1", "2^1 = 2", "2^2 = 4", "2^3 = 8", "2^4 = 16", "2^5 = 32", "2^6 = 64", 
"2^7 = 128", "2^8 = 256", "2^9 = 512", "2^10 = 1024", "2^11 = 2048", "2^12 = 4096",
"2^13 = 8192", "2^14 = 16384", "2^15 = 32768", "2^16 = 65536", "2^17 = 131072", 
"2^18 = 262144", "2^19 = 524288", "2^20 = 1048576"]
num = 0
usr = input("This is a program to show you the powers from 0 to 20. You pick a number between 0 and 20 and the program will show you all the powers within that range. type a number 1 - 20:   " )
print(results[0:usr])
```

The problem is that I can't seem to get the program to pull from the results string: 0 all the way up to the number that the user has inputed and print that.

This is the error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\spring 2015 classes\cosc 250\homework 4\question 1.py", line 15, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\spring 2015 classes\cosc 250\homework 4\question 1.py", line 13, in main
    print(results[0:usr])
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

I never came across this error before.  I'm still new to programming.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that "precomputing" your answers (like you did in your literal list of strings) is a valid solution for your problem?  I guess it would be much better to compute the output in a loop.

Comment: the only reason i precomputed my answers was because my assignment was just to make sure that the outcome was as it was supposed to be. However i think that your solution is better. sorry new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

`usr` is a string.  You need to convert it to an integer to use it as an index or a slice.  Try this:

```
print(results[0:int(usr)])
```

Comment: this is the same as above and it worked perfectly. really appreciate the help as i am trying to understand my first programming class. thank you

Comment: Glad it helps.  Good luck with your class, I hope you keep learning!  Programming is great!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `input` returns a `str` object.So apply `int` for slicing a `list`.

```
print(results[:int(usr)])
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and i did not have to use a for loop. All i had to do was to add + 1 after usr because it wasn't showing the last number of the user input.   Thank you  new to programming :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problems addressed in the other answers, I propose to use sth like this to compute the output in a loop:

```
for i in range(int(usr)):
  print "2^%d = %d" % (i, 2 ** i)
```

"Precomputing" the answers isn't very much about what to do with computers ;-)

Comment: Use a list format on a single line: `["2^%d = %d" % (i, 2 ** i) for i in range(int(usr))]`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Consider the displayed knowledge of the asker and rethink your proposal ;-)

Comment: He's printing a sliced list.

Comment: Yeah, but OP's solution was to use string literals of the expected answers.  I'm reluctant to scare him away with list comprehensions.

Comment: im interested in what this for loop does (again trying to learn so i can get better). this is printing the equation that will compute the list that i have called results without that list actually being there?

Comment: @jjflyV7: In your code, you created a large list `results` that contained all the powers of two from 0 to 20, and then you only printed the ones that you needed.  First of all, why would you do the math yourself, and write it into your code, when you could just make the computer do the math?  Second, why would you store all those powers of two when you may not need them.  Third, what if they enter a number bigger than 20?  Alfe's solution computes the powers automatically, and solves all those problems.